# Create indicator column threshold of values of another column for different rows with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,3,3],
             'phase': ['pre', 'post','pre', 'post','pre', 'post'],
             'n': [5,6,7,3,10,10]})
```

I want to create a new column (`new_col`) which indicates if `n>=5` for **both** `pre` & `post` by `id`.

The output dataframe looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,3,3],
             'phase': ['pre', 'post','pre', 'post','pre', 'post'],
             'n': [5,6,7,3,10,10],
             'new_col':[1,1,0,0,1,1]})
```

I would like to avoid any solution using `pd.pivot_table`

How could I do that ?

Comment: So not problem IF not tested  both pre/post like accepted answer?

Comment: Exactly, I have both pre&post for each id. Your solution is more generic indeed, the other though seemed easier to understand for me. Still useful though !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`pandas.Series.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) on specific condition:

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('id', sort=False)['n']\
    .transform(lambda x: (x >= 5).all().astype(int))
```

---

```
  id phase   n  new_col
0   1   pre   5        1
1   1  post   6        1
2   2   pre   7        0
3   2  post   3        0
4   3   pre  10        1
5   3  post  10        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test if both values `pre/post` exist per groups by replace them to missing values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with aggregate `set`s and compare this values, last map boolean Series to final column:

```
m = df['n'].ge(5)
s = df['phase'].where(m).groupby(df['id']).agg(set) == set({'pre','post'})
df['new_col'] =  df['id'].map(s).astype(int)
```

Or if possible test if number of unique values after `where` is equal `2`, in another words only `phase/post` values exist in `phase` column:

```
m = df['n'].ge(5)
s = df['phase'].where(m).groupby(df['id']).nunique().eq(2)
df['new_col'] =  df['id'].map(s).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
   id phase   n  new_col
0   1   pre   5        1
1   1  post   6        1
2   2   pre   7        0
3   2  post   3        0
4   3   pre  10        1
5   3  post  10        1
```

Another idea is test values separately with [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
m = df['n'].ge(5)
s1 = df.loc[m & df['phase'].eq('pre'), 'id']
s2 = df.loc[m & df['phase'].eq('post'), 'id']

df['new_col'] = df['id'].isin(np.intersect1d(s1, s2)).astype(int)
print (df)
   id phase   n  new_col
0   1   pre   5        1
1   1  post   6        1
2   2   pre   7        0
3   2  post   3        0
4   3   pre  10        1
5   3  post  10        1
```